# I am not able to open admin page in Django Framework

Tags: python, django, http, http-status-code-404, admin

I am trying to build a web app using the Django Framework. When, I go into localhost:8000/admin
the browser says: Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8000.

I am using PyCharm:

This is the error that comes up in the terminal:

Not Found: /

[21/Apr/2020 15:18:20] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2031
Following which the server cuts off

my app/urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
]
```

And my project/urls:

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('KMIO_page/', include('KMIO_app1.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Your logs show the path "/" being requested not "/admin/". If you try another path does the correct path show in the logs? "/" returning a 404 is to be expected since you do not have a path for it

Comment: I am a beginer in programming. Could you elaborte a lil.

Comment: I have tried 127.0.0.1:8000/KMIO_page. It does gives the HttpResponse

Comment: I did manually type "localhost:8000/admin/" in the browser. But the log is coming up as "/"

Answer (score 1):

In your logs, it says that you visited the **home** (`"/"`) path, not the path for your **admin** (`"/admin"`). The `urls.py` files seem to be good. However, you could add in your `app/urls.py` file, outside of the `urlpatterns` variable, the variable `app_name` and assign it the value of `KMIO_app1` or the name of your app. Last but not least, you could add in your `app/urls.py` file a **slash** (`"/"`) for your home directory. For example:

`app/urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('/', views.index),
]
```

I hope that helps. Please let me know if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I did manually type "localhost:8000/admin/" in the browser. But the log is coming up as "/"

Comment: Try to modify your code with my suggestions, please. To help you more I would like to know if my solution does not work too.

Comment: Could you please elaborate regarding adding the variable outside the url patters. I am a beginner in programming.. sorry

Comment: i added the "/". The server now gives a warning: WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W002) Your URL pattern '/' has a route beginning with a '/'. Remove this slash as it is unnecessary. If this pattern is targeted in an include(), ensure the include() pattern has a trailing '/'.

Comment: Please try to go to `http://localhost:8000/KMIO_page/` and send me the response

Comment: Try to add also the `app_name` global variable, in your `app/urls.py` file.

Comment: How should i add it? Should i add `x = KMIO_app1` before the `urlpatterns` and keep the rest the same?.. I know its a stupid question... But my coding capabilities are very limited.. :(

Comment: Yes, but in quotes (`app_name='KMIO_app1'`).

Comment: Still the same error. The server disconnects of connecting to localhost:8000/admin/

Comment: Then, at the `include()` alter it to `include('KMIO_app1.urls', namespace='KMIO_app1')`

Comment: Hey.. I realized something,.... this keeps happening only in my Mac. When I used my friends Windows computer,,, its working fine... Dont know why... I rechecked all the lines of code.. everything seems ok...But.. it still does not allow me to work on my personal computer

Comment: And.. i havent given the global variable or the nemecheck

Comment: Then, maybe copy the content, delete the files, and re-create them

Comment: I am sorry. I do not think I can help you anymore, you have really tried everything I could possibly imagine.

Comment: Appreciate your help.. Thanks for your time

Comment: Hey @georgekrax i got it. It seems its a bug in Django 3.0. When i tried it with 2.1 its working.. Thanks again

Comment: Nice to know, the problem was fixed